# Failure on installing UIMA SDK with Maven

Tags: uima

I am trying to use maven to install the UIMA sdk. To install UIMA from the terminal I entered, with the PWD being the apache-uima folder: mvn install

Everything looked successful until...

```
 [INFO] Apache UIMA Aggregate: aggregate-uimaj ............. SUCCESS [  0.029 s]
[INFO] Apache UIMA Base: uimaj-json: JSON ................. SUCCESS [  1.086 s]
[INFO] Apache UIMA Java SDK: uimaj ........................ FAILURE [  5.557 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:25 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-14T15:29:28-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 78M/1531M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:javadoc (javadocs-distr) on project uimaj: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/text/AnnotationIndex.java:29: error: self-closing element not allowed
[ERROR] * <code>AnnotationIndex idx = cas.getAnnotationIndex();</code> or <br/>
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/text/AnnotationIndex.java:30: error: malformed HTML
[ERROR] * <code AnnotationIndex<SomeJCasType> idx = jcas.getAnnotationIndex(SomeJCasType.class);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/text/AnnotationIndex.java:30: error: unknown tag: SomeJCasType
[ERROR] * <code AnnotationIndex<SomeJCasType> idx = jcas.getAnnotationIndex(SomeJCasType.class);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/jcas/JCas.java:596: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends Annotation> AnnotationIndex<T> getAnnotationIndex(Type type) throws CASRuntimeException;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/jcas/JCas.java:608: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends Annotation> AnnotationIndex<T> getAnnotationIndex(int type) throws CASRuntimeException;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/jcas/JCas.java:617: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends Annotation> AnnotationIndex<T> getAnnotationIndex(Class<T> clazz) throws CASRuntimeException;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/jcas/JCas.java:631: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends TOP> FSIterator<T> getAllIndexedFS(Class<T> clazz);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/jcas/JCas.java:699: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends TOP> FSIndex<T> getIndex(String label, Class<T> clazz);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/jcas/JFSIndexRepository.java:53: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends TOP> FSIndex<T> getIndex(String label);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/jcas/JFSIndexRepository.java:66: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends TOP> FSIndex<T> getIndex(String label, int type);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/jcas/JFSIndexRepository.java:82: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends Annotation> AnnotationIndex<T> getAnnotationIndex(int type);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/FSIndexRepository.java:46: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends FeatureStructure> FSIndex<T> getIndex(String label);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/FSIndexRepository.java:61: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends FeatureStructure> FSIndex<T> getIndex(String label, Type type) throws CASRuntimeException;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/FSIndexRepository.java:137: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends FeatureStructure> FSIterator<T> getAllIndexedFS(Type aType);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/CAS.java:477: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends FeatureStructure> T createFS(Type type) throws CASRuntimeException;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/CAS.java:711: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends AnnotationFS> AnnotationIndex<T> getAnnotationIndex();
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/CAS.java:721: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends AnnotationFS> AnnotationIndex<T> getAnnotationIndex(Type type) throws CASRuntimeException;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/CAS.java:735: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends AnnotationFS> AnnotationFS createAnnotation(Type type, int begin, int end);
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/jeise003/apache-uima/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/cas/CAS.java:744: warning: no @param for <T>
[ERROR] <T extends AnnotationFS> T getDocumentAnnotation();
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Command line was: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc @options @argfile
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/Users/jeise003/apache-uima/target/site/apidocs' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :uimaj
```

Any ideas on how to remedy the error?

Comment: which version are you trying to install? how did you download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDoc markup currently included in the UIMA source code is not up to the standards that the JavaDoc compiler in JDK 8 expects. Either you have to avoid building the JavaDoc, e.g. by using

```
mvn install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

or you have to switch to a Java 7 SDK before building UIMA, e.g. by setting your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point at a Java 7 installation. E.g. on OS X and assuming that version `1.7.0_60`you could use

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_60)
```

To get a list of installed JDKs on OS X, you could use

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

*Disclosure: I am on the Apache UIMA project*

Comment: Thanks! I decided not to use maven in the end!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to use the UIMA SDK in one of your Maven projects, you don't need to build it from source. You can just use it like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
    <artifactId>uimaj-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=uimaj for more UIMA projects.